# Как поднести 3 в степень i без использывания pow?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int n;
double j, i;
double sum = 0;
double prod = 1;
double dil;
int operationQuantity = 0;
printf("Enter your N: ");

scanf("%i", &n);

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        prod = (pow(3,i) * log(i+1));
        operationQuantity += 3;
    }
    dil = prod / (2j + 1);
    operationQuantity += 3;
    sum += dil;
    prod = 1;
    operationQuantity += 1;
}
printf("Result : %.7f\n", sum);
printf("Operations performed : %i\n", operationQuantity);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Если позарез нужно именно 3^i - напишите цикл для его вычисления...

Comment: Владислав, Вы бы внимательно читали, что Вам пишут в ответах и комментариях к Вашим-же вопросам...